TimeZones In Laravel Application
I have made a laravel application which save data in db as UTC. My client is in South Africa and he wants the records to be displayed in South Africa timezone. Any body guide me related to this.
Thanks
I tried to convert created-at to specific timezone using Carbon while displaying record any where in system.

You are able to use Carbon's setTimezone method to convert UTC to South Africa's time zone when displaying records

Do you have any specific question about this? Are you struggling with the PHP part or with the MySQL part?

"I tried to convert created-at to specific timezone using Carbon" - Great, did it work?  How did you do it?  What is the problem?

The problem is that it still display the difference of 2 hours

@TallalSaghir,Hi, How did you set the timezone? using .env or config/app.php?Have you tried my answer? If you tried what it is giving? If you want to set timezone through Carbon then please specify.

Edit your question, show your code.  Please read How to Ask.

Yes i have tried your solution but it is also sending time of this timezone to db which I don't want. If I save any record through eloquent it send Arican timezone time to db but I want to save as UTC and displayed as South Africa Time zone.
In app.php
'timezone' => env('TIME_ZONE', 'UTC'),
& in env
TIME_ZONE='Africa/Johannesburg'

Go to config/app.php and then search and edit the value of timezone like this.
 'timezone' => 'Africa/Johannesburg',

And then you need to clear the config settings stored in cache.
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
Then start the project again to see the chages.Try this.It will work.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwLzkSyxInM
followed this solved my problem. Thanks Guys.

If you are not getting proper timezone then first you need to set that time-zone into your .env file like this.
TIME_ZONE="country-name/area-name" 

Example:
TIME_ZONE="Asia/Kolkata"

After that you need to set that configuration into you config/app.php file like this.
'timezone' => env('TIME_ZONE', 'country-name/area-name'),

Example:
'timezone' => env('TIME_ZONE', 'Asia/Kolkata'),

So configure accordingly so that it will provide actual time.
